# Deployment of Django on Heroku Server Error (500) - Static file problem supposedly

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I have deployed my django project on Heroku (a very basic project without database).
The homepage is working but I have a Server Error (500) when I ask for a page with an imag from my Django project.
When I ask a page with an image from internet, it is working fine.
So my deduction is that the static files are not properly served but I don't find what it is wrong in my coding.

**Heroku log :**

*2020-09-10T04:31:02.719831+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.63.145.103 - - [10/Sep/2020:04:31:02 +0000] "GET /ES-home HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://hamaktest.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"*

*2020-09-10T04:31:02.720549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ES-home" host=hamaktest.herokuapp.com request_id=f9cc73c5-b170-4853-9ca7-368255259a52 fwd="117.196.158.121" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https*

In the Heroku build :

**Installing collected packages: asgiref, pytz, sqlparse, Django, gunicorn, whitenoise**

**remote:        Successfully installed Django-3.1.1 asgiref-3.2.10 gunicorn-20.0.4 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1 whitenoise-5.2.0**

**remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput**

**remote:        204 static files copied to '/tmp/build_72d0a30f/staticfiles', 481 post-processed.**

Any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Jytar

My settings.py file :

````
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.hamaktest.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hamak.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hamak.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'```
````

Answer (score 1):

When Django 3.1 came out, the way you referenced BASE_DIR changed. If you don't want to use the new version of Django, make sure you are adding the version you would like to use in your requirements. txt file. Anywhere in your settings.py file that has (os.path.join) would need to be replaced with the new syntax.

```py
# Old Way
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# New Way
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

However, if that is not the cause of your problem, I have found that by disabling static file collection during your push to heroku helps things out.

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

After you have a successful build with staticfiles collection disabled, I go into the heroku CLI and run

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However it did not help. 
First the new syntax is not recognized by heroku which gives : 
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
Furthermore disabling and then running the collectstatic does not do any difference.
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved.

Django accepts the backslash in the image code :  src="{% static "images\picture01.png" %}"

however Heroku don't.

I changed to src="{% static "images/picture01.png" %}"

And both Django and Heroku work.

I used backslash "" as shown in a Django tutorial. So be careful because it costed me a lot of time to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming to this common issue.

Make sure your HTML is tidy. I had commented-out incorrect references to CSS files in my base template that caused this issue for me. Just removing those fixed the problem.